# перенос на новую строку php

Tags: php, phpword

записываю в phpWord

```
while ($parent = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $blyudo .= $parent['namep'].".....".$parent['pricep']."р.\n";
}

$document->setValue('blyudo', $blyudo);
```

почему-то не переводит на новую строку "р.\n"

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать `\par` вместо `\n`

Comment: <w:br /> вот так срабатывает, разобрался

Comment: @Aslero [`$section->addTextBreak([$breakCount], [$fontStyle], [$paragraphStyle]);`](http://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elements.html#text-breaks) попробуйте это.

Comment: @Aslero `<w:br />` на сколько я понимаю для случаев, когда у вас есть какой-то текст, например, ввод пользователя в поле `textarea` с переводом строк и его нужно также вывести отформатированным в Word. То есть сделать замену, например, `\n` на `<w:br />`. А `addTextBreak()` лучше в том месте, где вы текст собираете «самостоятельно» в коде.

Comment: `\par` это параграф/абазац? это разные вещи с простым переносом строки

Answer (score 0):

Можно принудительно использовать тэг HTML для перевода строки `<br />`

```
$blyudo .= $parent['namep'].".....".$parent['pricep']."р.<br />";
```

Можно использовать функцию [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php), которая преобразует классические переводы строк в вебовские

Можно весь текст обернуть в теги [`<pre>тескт</pre>`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/pre).

Comment: `phpWord` это все умеет?